# How to set github token on Travis CI in a secure way?

Tags: travis-ci

I created an organization and a open source project under it, and uploaded the `.travis` file to do the building and deploying to github pages.

To deploy I need a github token, I found there is no "settings" page on the travis admin, so how I have to put the token in `.travis` file in plain text:

[image]

How to add it securely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the official document: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#defining-encrypted-variables-in-travisyml

Basically speaking, it needs these steps:

```
gem install travis
travis login  # input github account and password
travis encrypt github_token=<token> --add env.matrix
```

and it auto update the `.travis` file, so you only need to `git push` then.

For why there is no `settings` options, I guess it because the repo is under organization.